# Windows 10 On-Screen Keyboard minimize

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

I am looking for a way to stop the on-screen keyboard from being minimized. I have tried running a scheulded task every minute, which runs a powerwshell script, to check if it's minimized and if so restore. However the osk does not respond to the WinAPI calls to restore.

If anyone on knows how to stop the osk from being minimized I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

All cases online show that it is a known issue, but no solution or workaround.

The latest case on Microsoft Community in 2017

How to prevent on-screen keyboard from focus on last window minimize on it

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/how-to-prevent-on-screen-keyboard-from-focus-on/2e6c7d6b-f59e-4b95-b37e-487ff33dbda3?auth=1

I have submitted it via Feedback Hub app
[image]

Comment: Thanks Origami. However it's not the focus thats the issue for me as the screen is always on the same window. A quick bit of background is that the system is a clocking in/out system on a touch screen. Some users keep minimizing the keyboard and I need a way to get the keyboard to show it's self if someone does minimize it